# How do I edit a PHP object created using json_decode()?

Tags: php, json

I have no problems extracting the data from my object.  My problem is editing the data in the string and re-encoding it.  Every time I try to edit the object, it deletes all of the data in the object and only what I have edited is saved.

I would have assumed that this worked, but it doesn't.  Any suggestions?  ***(The below shows in object mode, I did try it as an associative array too and get the same result)***

```
    $jsonString = '[{ "stuff" : [{"name" : "name", "description" : "description", "id" : "id",}], "morestuff" : []}]';
    $name = 'new name';
    $description = 'new description';
    $obj_json = json_decode($jsonString);
    $obj_json->stuff->name = $name;
    $obj_json->stuff->description = $description;
    $newJsonString = json_encode($obj_json);
```

This is what is printed after:

```
{ "stuff" : {"name" : "new name", "description" : "new description"}}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of `$jsonString` too.

Comment: Try to print `$jsonString` and `$newJsonString` :)

Comment: well, does `stuff` actually exist to begin with? If not php will raise a Warning about trying to create a default object from an empty value

Comment: my strings are added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem in doing what you ask:

```
<?php

$jsonString = '{
    "stuff": {
        "name": "Original name",
        "description": "Original description",
        "foo": "Another field"
    }
}';
$name = "New name";
$description = "New description";

$obj_json = json_decode($jsonString);
$obj_json->stuff->name = $name;
$obj_json->stuff->description = $description;
$newJsonString = json_encode($obj_json);

echo $newJsonString . PHP_EOL;
```

... prints:

```
{"stuff":{"name":"New name","description":"New description","foo":"Another field"}}
```

You're probably reading or writing the wrong properties.

**Edit:**

Look carefully, your data is wrapped inside an array and `stuff` itself is also an array:

```
$jsonString = '[{ "stuff" : [{"name" : "name", "description" : "description", "id" : "id",}], "morestuff" : []}]';
               ^            ^                                                              ^                   ^
               |            \______________________________________________________________/                   |
               \_______________________________________________________________________________________________/
```

**Edit #2:** If fact, your data is [not valid JSON](http://jsonlint.com/) and `json_decode()` returns `null`:

```
$jsonString = '[{ "stuff" : [{"name" : "name", "description" : "description", "id" : "id",}], "morestuff" : []}]';
$obj_json = json_decode($jsonString);
var_dump($obj_json, json_last_error());
```

```
NULL
int(4)
```

Error #4 is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`: Syntax error, malformed JSON

Comment: I double checked and still not working.   I added my before and after strings above.

Comment: @user2212224 - What I told you, you're reading the wrong stuff. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems correct, but try this (maybe there's something with modifying object..) :

```
$obj_json = json_decode($jsonString, true); //as associative array
$obj_json['stuff']['name'] = $name;
$obj_json['stuff']['description'] = $description;
$newJsonString = json_encode($obj_json);
```

Use your json as associative array

Comment: I did and get the same result

Comment: You *can* edit PHP objects. There's no need to switch to arrays.